# Returning rvalue reference

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get my head around this code that I'm looking at:

```
class ShipFactory
{
public:
    Ship make_ship(....) { ... }

    static std::unique_ptr<ShipFactory>&& get_factory()
    {
        if (!m_factory) {
            m_factory.reset(new ShipFactory);
        }
        return std::move(m_factory);
    }

    ...
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<ShipFactory> m_factory;
};

std::unique_ptr<ShipFactory> ShipFactory::m_factory;

...

// used like this:
ship = ShipFactory::get_factory()->make_ship(...);
```

My question is about the get_factory method. I don't really understand why it's returning an rvalue reference to a std::unique_ptr or what that will do. I'm also not entirely convinced it's valid.

Comment: What would you return?

Comment: @Ayxan reference? A pointer maybe?

Comment: A dumb pointer to a smart pointer? This *is* returning an rvalue reference

Comment: But it's a factory, I don't get why you would move the factory out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `auto_ptr`, you can't copy a `unique_ptr` since that constructor is deleted and that would make no sense for the `unique_ptr` since it owns the memory it points to, but you can move it. This is what's happening here, resets a `unique_ptr`, and moves it. It has the same effect as:

```
auto ship = make_unique<ShipFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `std::move` doesn’t move anything; it merely **allows** a move to happen (and causes rvalue references that (presumably) move to be preferred in overload resolution).

Returning an rvalue reference (to something that is not destroyed when leaving the function!) is an **offer** of the object’s resources to the client:

```
auto s=ShipFactory::get_factory()->make_ship(…);  // use the current factory
auto f=ShipFactory::get_factory();  // take the whole current factory
```

Both lines create a factory if there is no current factory; the second causes there to be no current factory thereafter (but the `unique_ptr` `f` can still be used).

Comment: I think `std::move` should have been called something like `rvalue_cast` to make what it does more clear

Comment: @Ayxan: Maybe `as_rvalue`, like `as_const` which also infers the result type.